# The code cannot be used on outlet products

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

> The code cannot be used on **outlet products**.

what is it mean **outlet products**?

from my voucher fifa this sentence

Answer (score 2):

In the context of buying/selling things, I believe "outlet products" here is referring to "products which are sold in an [outlet store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlet_store)"

Comment: *outlet products* from EA , are they like *demo version, previous fifa version* or not?

Comment: @VIkeaMahun I don't know.  I believe in general outlet stores sell mostly the same products as elsewhere, but often at a cheaper price (since they're direct from the manufacturer).  I do know in some cases outlet stores can also sell special versions of things not available through other channels, but I'm not personally that familiar with EA's products or stores, so I don't really know whether they do that or not.